# ListView.builder show anything

Tags: flutter

AlertCardWidget is a widget that i wrote. I return it in itemBuilder but nothing shown. Here is my code:

```
       Flexible(
         child: Padding(
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                    state.data["datas"].map<Widget>((f) {

                          return AlertCardWidget(
                            positionId: "${f["8020074"]}",
                            shipowner: "${f["8020076"]}",
                            customer: "${f["8020170"]}",
                            salesRepresenter: "${f["8020176"]}",
                            operationRepresenter: "${f["8020177"]}",
                            textContentFontColor:
                                AppTheme(Theme.of(context).brightness)
                                    .cardFontBackgroundColor,
                            textfont: Colors.redAccent,
                          );
                        }).toList();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

No error to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have items that why I use `ListView`. The problom of using `Listview` instead `ListView.builder` is taking "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height error". The problem has solved when writing `Listview` like child of `Expanded` widget. Here is my code:

```
Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    child: ListView(
      children: state.data["datas"].map<Widget>((f) => AlertCardWidget(positionId: "${f["8020074"]}",
        shipowner: "${f["8020076"]}",
        customer: "${f["8020170"]}",
        salesRepresenter: "${f["8020176"]}",
        operationRepresenter: "${f["8020177"]}",
        textContentFontColor: AppTheme(Theme.of(context).brightness).cardFontBackgroundColor,
        textfont: Colors.redAccent,)).toList(),
    ),

  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your itemBuilder function does not return a value.

Edit: It should return a single Widget for every entry in your list. 
Something like this should work.
Also, Padding Widget is missing the padding property.

```
   Flexible(
     child: Padding(
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: state.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                     final f  = state.data[index];

                      return AlertCardWidget(
                        positionId: "${f["8020074"]}",
                        shipowner: "${f["8020076"]}",
                        customer: "${f["8020170"]}",
                        salesRepresenter: "${f["8020176"]}",
                        operationRepresenter: "${f["8020177"]}",
                        textContentFontColor:
                            AppTheme(Theme.of(context).brightness)
                                .cardFontBackgroundColor,
                        textfont: Colors.redAccent,
                      );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code, especially the state class? The itemBuilder should return a single Widget for every entry in the listview, not a list of widgets.

Comment: Yeah you are right. state is not a class. It is a state in bloc pattern. I fixed problem. Sharing now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly question, but why are you mapping a list into a ListView.builder?
Have you tried using the index for each iteration instead?
Because what I understand from that code is that every `["datas"]` item you've got will generate the whole list for as many times as `state.data.length` has.

Maybe try this out:

```
Flexible(
     child: Padding(
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: state.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return AlertCardWidget(
                        positionId: state.data[index]["datas"]["8020074"],
                        shipowner: state.data[index]["datas"]["8020076"],
                        customer: state.data[index]["datas"]["8020170"],
                        salesRepresenter: state.data[index]["datas"]["8020176"],
                        operationRepresenter: state.data[index]["datas"]["8020177"],
                        textContentFontColor:
                            AppTheme(Theme.of(context).brightness)
                                .cardFontBackgroundColor,
                        textfont: Colors.redAccent,
                      );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

If that doesn't work, would you mind showing us which data are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: The reason of using listview.builder is taken "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height error" at listview. state.data["datas"] has 1000 dynamic value that why i didnt write an entity for it. I know this is not the well coding but I didn't write all architecture. I was passing and I just included :)) And I fixed it. Will share now. Thanks mate